# Strings in Java: .equals()

Tags: java, string

I know that in order to see if the contents of two string match in Java we can use the `.equals()` method, but what could we use to see if they do not match? I've seen for example, lets say I have a string named :`password` that is set to `Cooper`

`(!password.equals("Cooper"));`

Does the exclamation mark mean that it is checking if the password does not equal `Cooper`?

Thank you

Comment: In the context of your example `!` means "not", it flips the result of the `boolean` value, so if `equals` returns `true` the `!` will make it `false`, you also see in normal comparisons, `a != b` would return `true` if `a` is not equal to `b` (for argument sake, just assume there numbers)

Comment: That's not an *exclamation mark*. That's the *not operator*.

Comment: @KenWhite The Unicode Consortium would disagree with you.  (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0021/index.htm)

Comment: @David: That would be relevant if the question was about Unicode or text. It isn't. It's about the Java programming language. In that language, it's the [*not operator*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm). (But that's OK. Everybody loves a pedant who points out irrelevant technicalities.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is **correct**. The `!` mark will flip the value of the `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two options to check whether the password is not equal to `Cooper`

```
 if(!password.equals("Copper"))
    {
        //do something
    }
```

or

```
if(!"Copper".equals(password))
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`(!password.equals("Cooper"))` is correct. ! sign will toggle the value of boolean result.

Instead of your statement, I would  prefer `(!"Cooper".equals(password))` because constant value on the left hand side will also eliminates chances of null pointer exception.

If the value of password is null then your statement will throw NullPointerException.